# Color ggplot by the label

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

For the following plot, I want to color the points according to the label, whereby all labels that contain "1" are red in their string, labels that contain "2" in their string are blue and labels that contain "3" in their string are green.

I'm not sure what the best approach is to achieve this.

```
label <- c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2", "A3", "B3", "C3")
val <- sample(1:100, 9, replace=FALSE)
d <- data.frame(label, val)
ggplot(d, aes(x=val,y=label)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that creating a variable with the categories and ploting them in the `colour` parameter.. Like this:

```
d <- data.frame(label, val) %>%
  mutate(category = substr(label, 2,2))


ggplot(d, aes(x=val,y=label)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = category), size = 15)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue","green"))
```

[image]